# Rails manifest file not found (deploying with Capistrano)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I'm trying to deploy a rails app using Capistrano, but it fails because there's no manifest file.

This is what I get when I run `cap production deploy`:

```
01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/list/releases/20171220202012/assets_manif…
✔ 01 influencerlist.io 0.048s
  WARN  Rails assets manifest file not found.
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host influencerlist.io: Rails assets manifest file not found.


Caused by:
Capistrano::FileNotFound: Rails assets manifest file not found.

Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:backup_manifest
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing on host influencerlist.io: Rails assets manifest file not found.
```

Any idea how to solve this issue? I've tried to find a solution but none of them seem to work.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the output of `cap production doctor`? Make sure to redact sensitive information, if any.

Answer (score 15):

I solved it, and I'm surprised with the solution...

I created two empty files in /shared/public/assets called .manifest.json and .sprockets-manifest.json, and it worked.

Comment: In my case, I solved my problem by creating an empty file `manifest.json` (without dot) in `shared/public/assets`.

Answer (score 12):

If you use webpacker in your Rails application, and you have completely disabled Sprockets, you might get the following error when trying to deploy: Rails assets manifest file not found. This happens inside the `deploy:assets:backup_manifest` task.

This task is build for Sprockets and does not work with webpacker. Simply skip it, by adding the following line to your `config/deploy.rb`:

```
Rake::Task["deploy:assets:backup_manifest"].clear_actions
```

https://makandracards.com/makandra/100898-fix-for-rails-assets-manifest-file-not-found-in-capistrano-deploy

Comment: It's a good idea to add also `Rake::Task["deploy:assets:restore_manifest"].clear_actions` to prevent `deploy:rollback` from crashing. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50650217/5828035) answer for more info.

Comment: This also applies to using other packers like vite and not using / needing sprockets

Answer (score 0):

@Paul Odeon's answer worked for me, and this also worked:

`set :assets_prefix, 'packs'`

Found at https://github.com/capistrano/rails/issues/235